# Extract column names for each column in dataframe where value is not NA over defined range of columns within dplyr function

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to write a function that takes a dataframe, a column that determines if a specific condition is met to subset the frame, a column with a numeric value, a grouping clause, and a subset name as arguments.

I would like the function to then check to see which of the columns across a defined range has a value that is not NA, and then extract the column names of those columns and append them to the dplyr table generated by the function for each summary row that dplyr generates as per the grouping clause. I am doing this over hundreds of subsets of a much bigger much more complicated dataframe so this is why I need a function that I can use over and over again.

The example dataset is as follows, I have updated it with the expanded dataset 
 apologies tot those who tried to help with the other one:

```
structure(list(superKey = c("12015", "12016", "12017", "12018", 
"22015", "22016", "22017", "22018", "32015", "1722016", "1722017", 
"1722018", "1732015", "1732016", "1732017", "1732018", "1742015", 
"1752015", "1752016", "1752017", "1762015", "1762018", "1772016", 
"1772017", "1772018", "1782015", "1782016", "1782017", "1782018", 
"1792015", "1792016", "1792017", "1792018", "1802015", "1812018", 
"1822016", "1832015", "1832017", "1842015", "1842016", "1842017", 
"1842018", "1852016", "1852017", "1852018", "2112018", "2122015", 
"2122016", "2122017", "2122018", "2132015", "2132016", "2132017", 
"2132018", "2142015", "2142016", "2142017", "2142018", "2152015", 
"2152016", "2152017", "2152018", "2162016", "2162017", "2172015", 
"2172016", "2172017", "2172018", "2182015", "2182016", "2182017", 
"2182018", "2192016", "2192017", "2192018", "2202015", "2202016", 
"2202017", "2202018", "2212015", "2212016", "2212017", "2212018", 
"2222015", "2222018", "2232015", "2232016", "2232017", "2232018", 
"2242015", "2242016", "2302018", "2312015", "2312016", "2312017", 
"2312018", "2322016", "2322017", "2332015", "2332016", "2332017", 
"2332018", "2342016", "2342017", "2432018", "2442015", "2442016"
), reportDate = c("2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", 
"2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2015-12-31", 
"2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", 
"2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", 
"2017-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", 
"2018-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", 
"2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2015-12-31", 
"2018-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2015-12-31", 
"2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", 
"2018-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", 
"2018-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", 
"2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2015-12-31", 
"2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", 
"2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2015-12-31", 
"2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", 
"2018-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", 
"2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2015-12-31", 
"2018-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", 
"2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", 
"2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2015-12-31", 
"2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", 
"2018-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31"), employerClass = c("class1", 
"class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", 
"class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", 
"class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", 
"class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", 
"class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", 
"class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", "class1", 
"class1", "class1", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", 
"class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", 
"class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", 
"class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", 
"class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", 
"class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class1", 
"class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", 
"class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", 
"class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", "class2", 
"class2"), healthRegion = c("Region1", "Region1", "Region1", 
"Region1", "Region2", "Region2", "Region2", "Region2", "Region2", 
"Region3", "Region3", "Region3", "Region4", "Region4", "Region4", 
"Region4", "Region3", "Region3", "Region3", "Region3", "Region3", 
"Region3", "Region2", "Region2", "Region2", "Region3", "Region3", 
"Region3", "Region3", "Region2", "Region2", "Region2", "Region2", 
"Region3", "Region4", "Region4", "Region3", "Region3", "Region1", 
"Region1", "Region1", "Region1", "Region2", "Region2", "Region2", 
"Region2", "Region2", "Region2", "Region2", "Region2", "Region3", 
"Region3", "Region3", "Region3", "Region3", "Region3", "Region3", 
"Region3", "Region4", "Region4", "Region4", "Region4", "Region2", 
"Region2", "Region3", "Region3", "Region3", "Region3", "Region3", 
"Region3", "Region3", "Region3", "Region1", "Region1", "Region1", 
"Region3", "Region3", "Region3", "Region3", "Region4", "Region4", 
"Region4", "Region4", "Region3", "Region3", "Region3", "Region3", 
"Region3", "Region3", "Region4", "Region4", "Region1", "Region1", 
"Region1", "Region1", "Region1", "Region3", "Region3", "Region2", 
"Region2", "Region2", "Region2", "Region1", "Region1", "Region1", 
"Region2", "Region2"), contactID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 172, 172, 172, 173, 173, 173, 173, 174, 175, 175, 175, 176, 
176, 177, 177, 177, 178, 178, 178, 178, 179, 179, 179, 179, 180, 
181, 182, 183, 183, 184, 184, 184, 184, 185, 185, 185, 211, 212, 
212, 212, 212, 213, 213, 213, 213, 214, 214, 214, 214, 215, 215, 
215, 215, 216, 216, 217, 217, 217, 217, 218, 218, 218, 218, 219, 
219, 219, 220, 220, 220, 220, 221, 221, 221, 221, 222, 222, 223, 
223, 223, 223, 224, 224, 230, 231, 231, 231, 231, 232, 232, 233, 
233, 233, 233, 234, 234, 243, 244, 244), funder1 = c(500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, NA, NA, NA, NA, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 500, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 500, 500, 500, 500, NA, NA, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 500, 500, 500, 500, NA, NA, 500, NA, NA), funder2 = c(1000, 
1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1000, NA, NA, NA, 1000, NA, 1000, 1000, 1000, NA, 
NA, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, NA, NA, 1000, 1000, 
1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, NA, NA, NA, 1000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1000, 1000, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1000, 1000, NA, NA, NA), funder3 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), funder4 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), funder5 = c(2500, 2500, 
2500, 2500, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2500, 2500, NA, NA, NA), others = c(3000, 
3000, 3000, 3000, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 3000, NA, NA, NA, 3000, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3000, 3000, 
3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3000, 
3000, 3000, 3000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3000, 3000, 
3000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 
3000, 3000, 3000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3000, 3000, NA, NA, 3000, 3000, 3000, 
3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3000, NA, 
NA, NA, 3000), total = c(7000, 7000, 7000, 7000, 1500, 1500, 
1500, 1500, 4000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 500, 500, 500, 500, 4500, 
500, 500, 500, 4500, 500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 3000, 3000, 4000, 
4000, 4500, 4500, 4500, 4500, 1500, 500, 500, 1500, 1500, 4000, 
4000, 4000, 4000, 0, 0, 0, 1500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3000, 3000, 3000, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1500, 1500, 4500, 4500, 3000, 3000, 3500, 3500, 
3500, 3500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 7000, 7000, 4000, 4000, 3500, 
3500, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 4000, 4000, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 6500, 3500, 500, 0, 3000), year = c("2015", "2016", "2017", 
"2018", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2016", "2017", 
"2018", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2015", "2016", 
"2017", "2015", "2018", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2016", 
"2017", "2018", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2018", 
"2016", "2015", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2016", 
"2017", "2018", "2018", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2015", 
"2016", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2015", 
"2016", "2017", "2018", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2017", 
"2018", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2016", "2017", "2018", 
"2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", 
"2015", "2018", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2016", 
"2018", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2016", "2017", "2015", 
"2016", "2017", "2018", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2015", "2016"
), serviceDivision = c("division1", "division1", "division1", 
"division1", "division2", "division2", "division2", "division2", 
"division1", "division1", "division1", "division1", "division2", 
"division2", "division2", "division2", "division1", "division2", 
"division2", "division2", "division2", "division2", "division2", 
"division2", "division2", "division3", "division3", "division3", 
"division3", "division1", "division1", "division1", "division1", 
"division2", "division2", "division2", "division2", "division2", 
"division1", "division1", "division1", "division1", "division1", 
"division1", "division1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "division2", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), numFunders = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1), multiFunder = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
), provFunders = c(8, 8, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 1, 
1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 
3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1), nonProvFunders = c(3, 4, 4, 4, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0, 2), provFundedOnly = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), provincialFunding = c(1500, 
1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1000, 0, 0, 0, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 1500, 500, 500, 500, 1500, 500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 
0, 0, 1000, 1000, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 500, 500, 1500, 
1500, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 0, 0, 0, 1500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 0, 0, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 500, 500, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 500, 500, 500, 500, 1000, 1000, 500, 
0, 0), nonProvincialFunding = c(5500, 5500, 5500, 5500, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3000, 0, 0, 0, 3000, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3000, 
3000, 3000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 
3000, 3000, 3000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 5500, 5500, 2500, 2500, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 
3000, 3000, 3000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5500, 2500, 0, 0, 3000), agencySize = c("greater than $15M", 
"greater than $15M", "greater than $15M", "greater than $15M", 
"greater than $15M", "greater than $15M", "greater than $15M", 
"greater than $15M", "less than $1M", "$7M - $15M", "$7M - $15M", 
"$7M - $15M", "$1M - $2M", "$1M - $2M", "$1M - $2M", "$1M - $2M", 
"$2M - $4M", "less than $1M", "less than $1M", "less than $1M", 
"$2M - $4M", "$2M - $4M", "$4M - $7M", "$4M - $7M", "$4M - $7M", 
"$1M - $2M", "$1M - $2M", "$2M - $4M", "$2M - $4M", "$2M - $4M", 
"$2M - $4M", "$4M - $7M", "$4M - $7M", "$2M - $4M", "less than $1M", 
"$1M - $2M", "$2M - $4M", "$2M - $4M", "$2M - $4M", "$2M - $4M", 
"$4M - $7M", "$4M - $7M", "$1M - $2M", "$1M - $2M", "$1M - $2M", 
"less than $1M", "less than $1M", "less than $1M", "less than $1M", 
"less than $1M", "$1M - $2M", "$2M - $4M", "$2M - $4M", "$1M - $2M", 
"less than $1M", "less than $1M", "less than $1M", "less than $1M", 
"$4M - $7M", "$4M - $7M", "$4M - $7M", "$4M - $7M", "greater than $15M", 
"greater than $15M", "$2M - $4M", "$2M - $4M", "$2M - $4M", "$2M - $4M", 
"$1M - $2M", "$1M - $2M", "$1M - $2M", "$1M - $2M", "$2M - $4M", 
"$2M - $4M", "$2M - $4M", "less than $1M", "less than $1M", "less than $1M", 
"less than $1M", "less than $1M", "less than $1M", "$1M - $2M", 
"$1M - $2M", "$7M - $15M", "$7M - $15M", "greater than $15M", 
"greater than $15M", "greater than $15M", "greater than $15M", 
"$1M - $2M", "$1M - $2M", "$2M - $4M", "less than $1M", "less than $1M", 
"less than $1M", "less than $1M", "$1M - $2M", "$1M - $2M", "less than $1M", 
"less than $1M", "less than $1M", "less than $1M", "$2M - $4M", 
"$2M - $4M", "$2M - $4M", "$1M - $2M", "$1M - $2M"), funder1funded = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), funder13funded = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE), funder2funded = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), funder3funded = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), funder4funded = c(TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), funder5funded = c(TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), sectorFunded = c("TRUE", 
"TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", 
"TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", 
"TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", 
"TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", 
"TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", 
"TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", 
"TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", 
"TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", 
"TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", 
"TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", 
"TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", 
"TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", 
"TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", 
"TRUE", "TRUE"), totHolder = c(7000, 7000, 7000, 7000, 1500, 
1500, 1500, 1500, 4000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
4500, 500, 500, 500, 4500, 500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 3000, 3000, 
4000, 4000, 4500, 4500, 4500, 4500, 1500, 500, 500, 1500, 1500, 
4000, 4000, 4000, 4000, 0, 0, 0, 1500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3000, 3000, 
3000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1500, 1500, 4500, 4500, 3000, 3000, 3500, 
3500, 3500, 3500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 7000, 7000, 4000, 4000, 
3500, 3500, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 4000, 4000, 500, 500, 
500, 500, 6500, 3500, 500, 0, 3000)), row.names = c(NA, -107L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Please note that provincialFunding is the sum of funders 1,2, and 3 and nonProvincialFunding is the sum of funders 4,5 and others.

The grouping clause passed to the function for this example is:

```
GRclauseSDregion <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "serviceDivision", "healthRegion")
```

There are multiple grouping clauses;

```
GRsectorProfile <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder")
GRclass1SD <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "serviceDivision")
GRsectorRegion <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "healthRegion")
GRclass1SDregion <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "serviceDivision", "healthRegion")
GRsectorAgencySize <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "agencySize")
GRclass1AgencySize <- c("year","employerClass", "multiFunder", "agencySize")
GRclass1SDagencySize <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "serviceDivision", "agencySize")
GRclass1SDregionAgencySize <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "serviceDivision", "healthRegion", "agencySize")
GRnonCLASS1AregionAgencySize <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "healthRegion", "agencySize")
GRclass1RegionAgencySize <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "healthRegion", "agencySize")
```

This is where I have gotten to:

```
# collapse function (funder)
collapsePassFunderArray <- function(df, funderTrueCol, fundingCol, groupClause, name) {
  funderTrueHolder <- enquo(funderTrueCol)
  fundingColHolder <- enquo(fundingCol)
  newDf <- df %>% 
    filter((!!funderTrueHolder) == TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(.dots = groupClause) %>% 
    summarise(funderName = name, 
              totFund = sum(total),
              minFunder = min(numFunders),
              maxFunder = max(numFunders),
              avgFunder = mean(numFunders, na.rm = TRUE),
              medianFunder = median(numFunders, na.rm = TRUE),
              provPerc = sum(provincialFunding)/sum(total),
              nonProvPerc = sum(nonProvincialFunding)/sum(total),
              funderPercProv = sum((!!fundingColHolder))/sum(provincialFunding),
              funderPercTot = sum((!!fundingColHolder))/sum(total),
              numAgencies = n_distinct(contactID),
              funders = simplify2array(apply(df[8:13], 1, 
                                            function(x)paste(names(df[6:11]) [which(!is.na(x))], collapse = " ")))
    )
}
```

Please note that the dataframe columns being selected [6:11] are those columns that would have the funders under scrutiny. This could change over time but I don't mind making the changes manually.

The following code produces the desired output when applied to the full dataset (the desired output being the space separated list of funders in the funders variable):

```
reproTable$funders <- simplify2array(apply(reproTable[6:11], 1, 
                                           function(x)paste(names(reproTable[8:13]) [which(!is.na(x))], collapse = " ")))
```

I run the following function call:

```
test1 <- collapsePassFunderArray(reproTable, funder1funded, funder1, GRclauseSDregion, "All")
```

Which gives the following error:

```
Error: Column `funders` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 107
```

Here is the desired output on the assumption that we are using the GRsectorRegion <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "healthRegion") grouping clause as per user @akrun request:

```
https://pastebin.com/1Z8vRLir
```

Sorry I had to use pastebin to paste the desired output source it went over the character limit.

Thank you to those who have tried to crack this I have tried to adapt the code but have run into the problems described in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update on 2020-04-01**

> *"Thing is I need the provvincialFunding summary value that it spits out to be the sum off all the provincial; funding within the subset set by the group clause. So when I run this on upper layers of aggregation like to the overall sector by the funder it starts giving me the wrong figures. Also when I take total out of the equation I can't run it on the sector as a whole."*

I had another stab at this based on your comments and the output shared via your *pastebin* link.  If this still doesn't answer your question, could I please ask that you specifically share examples of the "right" answers for a wider array of grouping clauses as this would hopefully make it easier to see where/when the method is failing.  For example, it is not clear to me what your expected output for *"aggregation like to the overall sector by the funder"* is.

Before showing the updated approach below, there are a number of caveats:

- There seems to be some sort of disconnect between the data shared in your OP and the output shared via *pastebin*. Specifically:

  - It seems as though the input data used to generate the output shared via *pastebin* differs somewhat from what was shared in your OP.
  - The *pastebin* data contains column `multiFunded` as opposed to `multiFunder` as per your OP
  - The *pastebin* data includes a `numFunder` column, though the `collapsePassFunderArray()` function in your OP does not
  - Your *pastebin* output does not contain a `medianFunder` column as per the `collapsePassFunderArray()` function in your OP
  - The values in your *pastebin* output for columns `funderPercProv` and `funderPercTot` confuse me: I would have assumed that `funderPercProv` should represent *total funding by funder `x` as a percentage of total provincial funding within the grouping clause*. However, despite the fact that there are several instances where, for example, total funding by `others` exceeds total provincial funding within your example grouping clause, the value of `funderPercProv` in your pastebin data never exceeds 1. This doesn't seem right to me, but perhaps I'm missing something.  Similarly, the `funderPercTot` values in your *pastebin* data don't seem to accord with the definition of *total funding by funder `x` as a percentage of total funding within the grouping clause*.  For example, if you look at the data from your OP for which the following filter holds true: `filter(year == 2015 & employerClass == 'class1' & multiFunder == F & healthRegion == 'Region3')`, then one can clearly see that funding by `others` amounts to 3000/3500 = 0.8571429 of total funding within the grouping clause `("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "healthRegion")`. However, your pastebin output reports this value as 0.14285714.

These issues make it very difficult to verify whether the following actually gives you what you need. Nevertheless, here's hoping that it does. I have assumed that the above-mentioned definitions for `funderPercProv` and `funderPercTot` are what is actually desired.

```r
# load required libraries
library(tidyverse)

# NB: define original input data as per OP and store as object reproTable

# first convert data into long format
reproTable_long <- reproTable %>%
  select(-totHolder) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = matches(
      '^funder\\d{1,}$|^others$|^total$|^provincialFunding$|nonProvincialFunding'
    ),
    names_to = 'funder'
  )

 # define function of interest 
collapsePassFunderArray <- function(df, FunderVal, groupClause, name) {
  reproTable_long %>% 
    group_by(.dots = GRsectorRegion) %>% 
    filter(sum(value[funder == FunderVal], na.rm = T) > 0) %>%
    summarise(
      funderName = name,
      totFund = sum(value[funder == 'total'], na.rm = T),
      minFunder = min(numFunders, na.rm = T),
      maxFunder = max(numFunders, na.rm = T),
      avgFunder = mean(numFunders, na.rm = TRUE),
      medianFunder = median(numFunders, na.rm = TRUE),
      provPerc = sum(value[funder == 'provincialFunding'], na.rm = T) / 
        sum(value[funder == 'total'], na.rm = T),
      nonProvPerc = sum(value[funder == 'nonProvincialFunding'], na.rm = T) / 
        sum(value[funder == 'total'], na.rm = T),
      funderPercProv = sum(value[funder == FunderVal], na.rm = T) / 
        sum(value[funder == 'provincialFunding'], na.rm = T),
      funderPercTot = sum(value[funder == FunderVal], na.rm = T) / 
        sum(value[funder == 'total'], na.rm = T),
      numAgencies = n_distinct(contactID),
      funders = funder[!is.na(value) & !funder %in% c('total', 'provincialFunding', 'nonProvincialFunding')] %>% 
        unique() %>% 
        paste( collapse = " ")
    ) %>% 
    ungroup()
} 


 # define grouping clauses
GRclauseSDregion <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "division", "healthRegion")
GRsectorProfile <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder")
GRcsseaSD <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "serviceDivision")
GRsectorRegion <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "healthRegion")
GRcsseaSDregion <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "serviceDivision", "healthRegion")
GRsectorAgencySize <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "agencySize")
GRcsseaAgencySize <- c("year","employerClass", "multiFunder", "agencySize")
GRcsseaSDagencySize <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "serviceDivision", "agencySize")
GRcsseaSDregionAgencySize <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "serviceDivision", "healthRegion", "agencySize")
GRnonCSSEAregionAgencySize <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "healthRegion", "agencySize")
GRcsseaRegionAgencySize <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "healthRegion", "agencySize")

# test a few clauses for funder1, funder2, etc
others_GRclauseSDregion <- collapsePassFunderArray(reproTable_long, 'others', GRclauseSDregion, name = 'All')
funder1_GRcsseaSD <- collapsePassFunderArray(reproTable_long, 'funder1', GRcsseaSD, name = 'All')
funder2_GRcsseaAgencySize <- collapsePassFunderArray(reproTable_long, 'funder2', GRcsseaAgencySize, name = 'All')
funder5_GRnonCSSEAregionAgencySize <- collapsePassFunderArray(reproTable_long, 'funder5', GRnonCSSEAregionAgencySize, name = 'All')
```

---

**Original reponse**

Thank you for the careful explanation and the solid reprex!

> I just can't seem to wrap my head around what I would do here to get the desired result. I think that I have to make quosures for the function within the function and have read and reread the vignetter on programming in dplyr several times but I'm just not getting it.

You've already highlighted that the following segment of your `collapsePassFunderArray` array function works perfectly fine on the ungrouped data:

```r
funders = simplify2array(apply(df[8:13], 1,
                               function(x)
                                 paste(names(df[8:13]) [which(!is.na(x))], collapse = " "))
```

I suspect that (though am not 100% certain), in it's current form, this function operates on the original, unfiltered and ungrouped  input data `df` and not on the filtered and grouped data that you are piping into your `summarise` call inside `collapsePassFunderArray()`.  If this is indeed the case, the error you receive makes sense: The function is still operating on the original, 7-row input data, and will therefore try to return 7 rows.

As for generating the results you want:  I took a stab at it taking a somewhat different, but hopefully still useful, approach.  Below, I share the reprex first, then attempt to explain it further thereafter:

```r
# load required libraries
library(tidyverse)

# define data using the data pasted in the original post

# define function of interest 
collapsePassFunderArray <- function(df, FunderVal, groupClause) {

  df %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = matches('^funder\\d{1,}$|^others$|^total$'), names_to = 'funder') %>% 
    filter(funder != 'total')  %>% 
    group_by(.dots = groupClause) %>% 
    filter(sum(value[funder == FunderVal], na.rm = T) > 0) %>% 
    summarise(
      funderName = first(name),
      totFund = sum(value, na.rm = T),
      minFunder = min(numFunders),
      maxFunder = max(numFunders),
      avgFunder = mean(numFunders, na.rm = TRUE),
      medianFunder = median(numFunders, na.rm = TRUE),
      provPerc = first(provincialFunding) / totFund,
      nonProvPerc = first(nonProvincialFunding) / totFund,
      funderPercProv = sum(value[funder == FunderVal]) / first(provincialFunding),
      funderPercTot = sum(value[funder == FunderVal]) / totFund,
      numAgencies = n_distinct(contactID),
      funders = paste(funder[!is.na(value)], collapse = " ")
    )
}

# define grouping clause
GRclauseSDregion <- c("year", "employerClass", "multiFunder", "division", "healthRegion")

# test for funder1, funder2, etc
test1 <- collapsePassFunderArray(reproTable, 'funder1', GRclauseSDregion)
test2 <- collapsePassFunderArray(reproTable, 'funder2', GRclauseSDregion)
testothers <- collapsePassFunderArray(reproTable, 'others', GRclauseSDregion)
```

Here's my attempt at explaining the function:

- Take the input data and first reshape it from wide to long (I find it much, much easier to work with data in long format).  The code to reshape to long is quite flexible as it relies on regex matching, rather than positional targeting, to identify the relevant *funder* columns.  Note, however, that this code assumes that your *funder* columns will always either be called `funder*`, where `*` represents a numerical suffix, or `others`.  If this is the case, the code should be able to deal with an arbitrary number of funder columns. Alternatively, you could simply adapt the regex used.
- Next, remove all instances where the new `funder` column has a value of `total` (it is always possible to recreate this value based on the other rows in the data)
- Next, apply your chosen grouping clause
- With the data grouped, we now use filter to ensure that we only retain data for all groups for which the total funding provided by the funder in question is greater than zero
- Next we jump into the `summarise` call. Note that most of the changes from your original function that have been made here are simply there to account for the fact that the data has been pivoted from wide to long.  The only substantive difference is the way in which I create the collapsed string of funders.  Specifically, I simply subset all of the rows to retain only those funders who had non `NA` contributions.  Then I collapse these into a space-separated character string.

My testing suggests that the results align with what is generated by the code you provided in your original post.  That said, I realise that I've substantively altered the way the function works and, more importantly, the way it needs to be called.  Perhaps this is not what you're looking for, but I hope it's on the right track!

Comment: Hi there. Thank you so much for taking a run at this. I tried implementing your solution but ran into a snag. I've been at it for a couple of days. Thing is I need the provvincialFunding summary value that it spits out to be the sum off all the provincial; funding within the subset set by the group clause. So when I run this on upper layers of aggregation like to the overall sector by the funder it starts giving me the wrong figures.  Also when I take total out of the equation I can't run it on the sector as a whole. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @robbieNukes. There may be a way to achieve this with the data in its current format, but: is your _original_ data in exactly the same format as the output you show in your initial question, or is that after some wrangling?  If the original data is actually in a long format to start with, it may be far easier to try and use that "as is" to answer your question.  It would be good to get clarity on this (and potentially see the original data structure).  In the meantime, I'll have a think about how one could achieve what you're after using the data in its current, wide format.

Comment: Hi @hendrikvanb thanks so much once again for your efforts on this. I updated the data structure to show the levels as well as outlining the group clauses but the principle is the same. This is the source data but further wrangling is very much a possibility. The hangup I ran into with your solution was that the provincialFunding for each agency needs to be summed.

Comment: It worked!!!!!  Thank you SO MUCH!!!! I can't begin to tell you how important this is (I literally can't because of my NDA) but I can tell you that I appreciate this SOOOO MUCH!!! All best to you in all things!!!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `group_by_at` to pass string column names along with `pmap` from `purrr` for `paste`ing the elements

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
collapsePassFunderArray <- function(df, funderTrueCol, 
                   fundingCol, groupClause, name) {
  funderTrueHolder <- enquo(funderTrueCol)
  fundingColHolder <- enquo(fundingCol)
  df %>% 
    filter((!!funderTrueHolder) == TRUE) %>% 
    mutate(funder = pmap_chr(select(., matches("^(funder\\d+$)|(^others$)")),
       ~ {x1 <- c(...)
         str_c(names(x1)[!is.na(x1)], collapse=" ")
         }))  %>%
    group_by_at(vars(intersect(groupClause, names(.)), 'funder')) %>%
    summarise(funderName = name, 
              totFund = sum(total),
              minFunder = min(numFunders),
              maxFunder = max(numFunders),
              avgFunder = mean(numFunders, na.rm = TRUE),
              medianFunder = median(numFunders, na.rm = TRUE),
              provPerc = sum(provincialFunding)/sum(total),
              nonProvPerc = sum(nonProvincialFunding)/sum(total),
              funderPercProv = sum((!!fundingColHolder))/sum(provincialFunding),
              funderPercTot = sum((!!fundingColHolder))/sum(total),
              numAgencies = n_distinct(contactID))




    }
```

-testing

```
test1 <- collapsePassFunderArray(reproTable, funder1funded, funder1, GRclauseSDregion, "All")
test1$funder
#[1] "funder1 funder3 funder5 others"  "funder1 funder3 funder4 funder5" "funder1 funder3 funder4 funder5"
#[4] "funder1 funder3 funder5"

test2 <- collapsePassFunderArray(reproTable, funder2funded, funder2, GRclauseSDregion, "All")
test2$funder
#[1] "funder2 funder4"        "funder2 funder4 others" "funder2 funder4 others"
testothers <- collapsePassFunderArray(reproTable, otherFunded, others, GRclauseSDregion, "All")
testothers$funder
#[1] "funder1 funder3 funder5 others" "funder2 funder4 others"         "funder2 funder4 others"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I think its almost there except that the group_by_at is grouping by the combinations of funders which gives way too much granularity. I'm trying to get all of the funders names within the grouping clause provided, so what this version odes is creates a subgroup for every combination of funders where I need all of the funders within the grouping clause to be rolled up into one vector. I'm going to play around with this to see if I can make it work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @robbieNukes i was looking at the other output while creating this function.  Also, I didn't change that much from your function

Comment: Absolutely! Awesome approach with pmap_chr it looks like its creating a new grouping for every combination of the funders here now, not on the array of all funders contained in the mutated variable.  I'm trying to bring in the mutated funder variable into the summarize so it doesn't group on it but then I get an error with the intersect function. I updated the reproTable above to reflect the complexity of the dataset.

Comment: @robbieNukes the `pmap` step is actually looping over each row, just like your `apply` with MARGIN = 1.  if it needs to be after the grouping step, ie.. in summarise, it can rearranged from the mutate to summarise.

Comment: @robbieNukes iit may be better if you can update with the expected output for crossmatching

Comment: Hi @akrun I have mocked up the desired output here thank you so much for your help I tried to rearrange the pmap step into the summarize but i kept getting the same rollup error (length of 1, not 1407 etc...) Here is the desired output on pastebin 

https://pastebin.com/1Z8vRLir